# UWP FileWatcher BackgroundTask

Tags: uwp, background-task, file-watcher

I'm new here and currently programming a Windows 10 Desktop UWP for my company, which should check a txt-file by a background task and update the UWP tile / UWP secondary tile.

Checking the users libraries by using the StorageLibraryContentChangedTrigger is simple and works fine. But my company says, that the users libraries is a not an good idea to save a txt-file (sample 1):

```
StorageLibrary videosLib = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Videos);
StorageLibraryContentChangedTrigger videoTrigger = StorageLibraryContentChangedTrigger.Create(videosLib);

taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
taskBuilder.Name = taskNameFileChanged;
taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = taskFileChangedEntryPoint;
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(videoTrigger);
register = taskBuilder.Register();
```

Checking the app local folder by using this code (sample 2):

```
List<string> typeFilter = new List<string>();
typeFilter.Add(".txt");
var queryoptions = new Windows.Storage.Search.QueryOptions(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, typeFilter);
var query = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);

 //subscribe on query's ContentsChanged event
 query.ContentsChanged += Query_ContentsChanged;


 private void Query_ContentsChanged(Windows.Storage.Search.IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args)
 {
     Debug.WriteLine("File has changed!!!!");
 }
```

is also working, but only if the UWP is opened / active.

Q1:
Is there a way, that triggers the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, so i can say e.g. "ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.ContentChangedTrigger"?

Q2:
If Q1 is not possible, how can i else check the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder for content changes by a background task?

Q3:
I know that an UWP runs in a Sandbox, but can an UWP have a restricted access to a windows registry key? Read access would already suffice.

Thanks in advance for the answers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1: Is there a way, that triggers the
>   ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, so i can say e.g.
>   "ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.ContentChangedTrigger"?

No as far as I'm concerned. However, using the [StorageLibraryContentChangedTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.storagelibrarycontentchangedtrigger), you can put the text file in the Documents library, maybe it makes more sense for your company. I would tell your company that having an ideal UWP app is a dream at the moment.

> Q2: If Q1 is not possible, how can i else check the
>   ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder for content changes by a
>   background task?

You can register a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger) background task, then check the last modified date of the file every 15 minutes in background. Another alternative way is using [push notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-choosing-a-notification-delivery-method) to update the tile, instead of a local text file.

> Q3: I know that an UWP runs in a Sandbox, but can an UWP have a
>   restricted access to a windows registry key? Read access would already
>   suffice.

No.

**Edit**

You need the [Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) restricted capability to access the Documents folder. To make it work for development, manually add the entry to the xml Package.manifest file:

```
<uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/>
```

In order to submit the app to the Store with this restricted capability, you need to request for the submission.

> Anyone may request access to this capability for store submission.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-).

I've already thought that there is no trigger like "ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.ContentChangedTrigger".

With the "Documents library" i always get an "access denied" error message. All other libraries work perfectly.

When i look into the Package.appxmanifest file with Visual Studio 2017, i can only select the libraries "Pictures", "Music" and "Videos" as capabilities.

If i am not mistaken, the access to the "Documents library" is for Microsoft only.

Comment: @T.Fischer I updated the answer for the Documents library. It is not Microsoft only but you need to request the access for submission.